# Пунктуация в предложении: "Очень долго вынашивал идею создания своей книги — и вот наконец созрел"

Tags: пунктуация

> Очень долго вынашивал идею создания своей книги — и вот наконец созрел.

Есть ли ошибки в данном предложении?

Answer (score 1):

**Очень долго вынашивал идею создания своей книги — и вот наконец созрел.**

1. Ставить ли тире? Да, ставить.

> § 169. Тире ставится между двумя сказуемыми и между двумя независимыми предложениями, если во втором из них содержится неожиданное присоединение или резкое противопоставление по отношению к первому (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/158-tire)

2. Выделять ли запятыми "наконец"? Нет, не выделять.

В данном предложении слово "наконец" употреблено в роли члена предложения (в знач. «в конечном итоге, после всего, под конец»), а не как вводное. (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_436)

3. Ставить ли запятую после "вот"? Нет, не ставить.

В данном предложении частица "вот" служит для усиления.

> ВОТ, частица
>   Не требует постановки знаков препинания.
>   http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_95

Примеры:

Он строил-строил — и наконец построил (Эдуарду Успенскому — 80 лет) https://www.novayagazeta.ru/articles/2017/12/22/75016-on-stroil-stroil-i-nakonets-postroil

Я спал, а сознание всё мусолило его образ, разжевывало, пытаясь понять, что к чему, ― и вот наконец выдало решение. [Андрей Волос. Недвижимость (2000) // «Новый Мир», 2001]